# XP app won't increase cpu utilization

Tags: c++

I am trying to fix a problem with a legacy Visual Studio win32 un-managed c++ app which is not keeping up with input. As a part of my solution, I am exploring bumping up the class and thread priorities.

My PC has 4 xeon processors, running 64 bit XP. I wrote a short win32 test app which creates 4 background looping threads, each one running on their own processor. Some code samples are shown following. The problem is that even when I bump the priorities to the extreme, the cpu utilization is still less than 1%.

My test app is 32 bit, running on WOW64.  The same test app also utilizes less than 1% cpu utilization on a 32 bit xp machine. I am an administrator on both machines. What else do I need to do to get this to work?

```
DWORD __stdcall ThreadProc4 (LPVOID)
{
    SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(),THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int p = i;
            int red = p *5;
            theClassPrior4 = GetPriorityClass(theProcessHandle);
        }
        Sleep(1);
    }
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(...)
{
...
    theProcessHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
    BOOL theAffinity = GetProcessAffinityMask(
        theProcessHandle,&theProcessMask,&theSystemMask);

    SetPriorityClass(theProcessHandle,REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);

    DWORD  threadid4 = 0;
    HANDLE thread4   = CreateThread((LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,
        0,
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadProc4,
        NULL,
        0,
        &threadid4);

    DWORD_PTR theAff4 = 8;
    DWORD_PTR theAf4 = SetThreadAffinityMask(thread1,theAff4);
    SetThreadPriority(thread4,THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);
    ResumeThread(thread4);
```

Comment: The problem is that your application isn't CPU bound. You need to do some more investigations to see whether it's IO bound or disk bound.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you want it to actually eat CPU time, you'll want to remove that 'Sleep' call - your 'processing' is taking no significant amount of time, and so it's spending most of it's time sleeping.

You'll also want to look at what the optimizer is doing to your code. I wouldn't be totally surprised if it completely removed 'p' and 'red' (and the multiply) in your loop (because the results are never used). You could trying marking 'red' as volatile, that should force it to not remove the calculation.